# Page is too big for the window

Tags: html, css

When the page is loaded it is too big for the page. I have absolutely positioned elements on the page but none of them go out of the bounds of the page when I have a window large enough to contain the content (1900px/etc). In other words all of the elements fit inside the body without exceeding its borders on the devices that I have been testing on. I have a div that spans 100% of the page and there is a horizontal scroll bar and the div can be moved to the left about 100px and doesn't span the whole page. When the page is parsed is there some sort of padding/etc that would make the page extend past it's outer-most elements a little and if so, how would I reset this?

http://jsfiddle.net/7CPfz/

```
<html >
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>    
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
        <title>Tipsy Trolley Price Estimator</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=1400px, user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1.0">

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>

    <body>
            <img id="homeLink" src="homeLinkImage.png">
            <div id="pageDivider"></div>
            <div id="homeLinkBackground"></div>
            <div id = "slider"><img id="sliderImage" src="haha.png"></div>
            <img id = "busType1" class="busType1 busType" src="busType1.png">
            <img id = "busType2" class="busType2 busType" src="busType2.png">
            <img id = "busType3" class="busType3 busType" src="busType3.png">
            <img  id ="busTypeBack1" class="busType1 busTypeBack" src="busTypeBack.png">
            <img  id ="busTypeBack2"  class="busType2 busTypeBack" src="busTypeBack.png">
            <img  id ="busTypeBack3"  class="busType3 busTypeBack" src="busTypeBack.png">
            <div id="contactLinkContainer">
                <img  id ="facebook" src="facebookLogo.png">
                <img  id ="email" src="email.png">
                <img  id ="phone" src="phone.png">
                <img  id ="facebookBack"  src="facebookLogoBack.png">
                <img  id ="emailBack"  src="emailBack.png">
                <img  id ="phoneBack"  src="phoneBack.png">
            </div>
            <div id="contactContainer"></div>
            <div id="busType1Ring" class="busTypeRing"></div>
            <div id="busType2Ring" class="busTypeRing"></div>
            <div id="busType3Ring" class="busTypeRing"></div>
            <div id="sliderContainer">
                <div id="sliderDiv1"  class="sliderDiv"><p class="sliderNumbers">1</p></div>
                <div id="sliderDiv2"  class="sliderDiv"><p class="sliderNumbers">2</p></div>
                <div id="sliderDiv3"  class="sliderDiv"><p class="sliderNumbers">3</p></div>
                <div id="sliderDiv4"  class="sliderDiv"><p class="sliderNumbers">4</p></div>
                <div id="sliderDiv5"  class="sliderDiv"><p class="sliderNumbers">5</p></div>
                <div id="sliderDiv6"  class="sliderDiv"><p class="sliderNumbers">6</p></div>
                <div id="sliderDiv7"  class="sliderDiv"><p class="sliderNumbers">7</p></div>
                <div id="sliderDiv8"  class="sliderDiv"><p class="sliderNumbers">8</p></div>
            </div>
            <div id="pickBusDiv"><img  id ="pickBusImg"  src="hWBus.png"><p id="pickBusP">Pick your bus</p></div>
            <div id="pickDayDiv"><img  id ="pickDayImg"  src="pickDay.png"><p id="pickDayP">Pick a day</p></div>
            <div id="pickHourDiv"><img  id ="pickHourImg"  src="sliderPic.png"><p id="pickHourP">Pick the number of hours form pickup to drop off</p></div>
            <div id="pickSocialDiv"><img  id ="pickSocialImg"  src="wholla.png"><p id="pickSocialP">Call, Facebook message, or email to check availability and confirm price</p></div>
            <div id="priceDisplayContainer"></div>
            <div id="hWorksBreak"></div>
            <div id="priceDisplay"><p id="priceDisplay"></p></div>
            <p id="saturdayBut" class="dayButton">Saturday</p>
            <p id="weekBut" class="dayButton">Sunday - Friday</p>
            <img id="saturdayButSelect" class="dayButtonSelector" src="saturdayBut.png">
            <img id="weekButSelect" class="dayButtonSelector" src="weekDayBut.png">
            <img id="saturdayButSelectBack" class="dayButtonSelector" src="daySelectBack.png">
            <img id="weekButSelectBack" class="dayButtonSelector" src="daySelectBack.png">
            <div id="HworksContainer" ></div>
            <div id="contactContainer" ></div>
            <p id="howItWorks">How it Works</p>
            <div id="saturdayButSurround" class="butSurround"></div>
            <div id="weekButSurround" class="butSurround"></div>




    </body>
</html>
<style>
body
{


    background: url(textured_paper.png);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 500px 500px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    height: 1000px;
     margin: 0;
   padding: 0;


}
#saturdayButSurround
{
    margin-left: -450px;
}
#weekButSurround
{
    margin-left: 40px;
    opacity:0;
}
.butSurround
{
    top:520px;
    position:absolute;
    height:40px;
    width:900px;
    border:5px solid blue;
    opacity:.5;
    border-radius: 20px;
    left:50%;
    z-index: 0;
    opacity:0;

}
#pickBusDiv
{
    position: absolute;
    height:150px;
    width: 200px;
    top:1250px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-600px;
    z-index: 4;
}
#pickBusImg
{
    height:100px;
}
#pickBusP
{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Arial Black", "Arial Bold", Gadget, sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    top:-100px;
    left:20px;
}
#pickDayDiv
{
    position: absolute;
    height:150px;
    width: 200px;
    top:1250px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-300px;
    z-index: 4;
}
#pickDayImg
{
    height:100px;
}
#pickDayP
{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Arial Black", "Arial Bold", Gadget, sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    top:-100px;
    left:-10px;
}
#pickHourDiv
{
    position: absolute;
    height:150px;
    width: 350px;
    top:1250px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-120px;
    z-index: 4;
}
#pickHourImg
{
    position: absolute;
    width:200px;
    left:80px;
    top:30px;
}
#pickHourP
{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Arial Black", "Arial Bold", Gadget, sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    top:-100px;
    text-align: center;
}
#pickSocialDiv
{
    position: absolute;
    height:150px;
    width: 400px;
    top:1250px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:280px;
    z-index: 4;
    text-align: center;
}
#pickSocialImg
{
    height:100px;
}
#pickSocialP
{
    width:100%;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Arial Black", "Arial Bold", Gadget, sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    top:-100px;
}
#howItWorks
{
    position: absolute;
    top:960px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left: -300px;
    width: 600px;
    z-index: 3;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Arial Black", "Arial Bold", Gadget, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;

}
#facebook
{
    position: absolute;
    top:5px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left: -520px;
    height: 70px;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#email
{
    position: absolute;
    top:5px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
    height: 70px;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#phone
{
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left: 310px;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor:pointer;

}
#facebookBack
{
    position: absolute;
    top:5px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left: -520px;
    height: 70px;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
}
#emailBack
{
    position: absolute;
    top:5px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
    height: 70px;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
}
#phoneBack
{
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left: 310px;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
}
#contactLinkContainer
{

    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left:0;
    height:150px;
    top:860px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#HworksContainer
{
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left top,
        right bottom,
        color-stop(0, rgb(17, 0, 252)),
        color-stop(1, rgb(0, 213, 255)));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right bottom, rgb(17, 0, 252) 0%, rgb(0, 213, 255) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right bottom, rgb(17, 0, 252) 0%, rgb(0, 213, 255) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right bottom, rgb(17, 0, 252) 0%, rgb(0, 213, 255) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right bottom, rgb(17, 0, 252) 0%, rgb(0, 213, 255) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgb(17, 0, 252) 0%, rgb(0, 213, 255) 100%);
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left:0;
    height:600px;
    top:840px;
    opacity:.5;
    z-index: 0;
}
#hWorksBreak
{
    position:absolute;
    width: 96%;
    left:2%;
    height:2px;
    top:960px;
    opacity:.5;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 2;
}
#priceDisplay
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    font-size:50px;
    text-align: center;
}
.dayButtonSelector
{
    position: absolute;
    width:110px;
    height:110px;
    top:465px;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor:pointer;

}
#saturdayButSelect
{
    left:50%;
    margin-left: -250px;

}
#weekButSelect
{
    left:50%;
    margin-left: 150px;
}
#saturdayButSelectBack
{
    left:50%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    z-index: 0;

}
#weekButSelectBack
{
    left:50%;
    margin-left: 150px;
    z-index: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
#mainContainer
{
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
    width:1400px;
    height:1000px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    left:0;
}
.dayButton 
{


    font-size:30px;
    width:400px;
    height:20px;
    text-align: center;
    top:495px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor:pointer;
    opacity: 0;
}
#saturdayBut
{
    left:50%;
    margin-left: -380px;    
}
#weekBut
{
    left:50%;
    margin-left: 20px;
}


#priceDisplayContainer
{
    position:absolute;
    height:130px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left: 150px;
    width: 350px;
    background-color: white;
    top:630px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: 0;
    opacity:.8;
}
#priceDisplay
{
    position:absolute;
    height:130px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left: 150px;
    width: 350px;
    z-index: 1;
    top:670px;

}
.sliderNumbers
{
    position: absolute;
    top:-100px;
    left:-14px;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: "Arial Black", "Arial Bold", Gadget, sans-serif;
}
.sliderDiv
{
    top:60px;
    position:absolute;
    height:8px;
    width:3px;
    background-color: black;
}
#sliderDiv1
{
    left:5px;
}
#sliderDiv2
{
    left:78px;
}
#sliderDiv3
{
    left:155px;
}
#sliderDiv4
{
    left:233px;
}
#sliderDiv5
{
    left:311px;
}
#sliderDiv6
{
    left:389px;
}
#sliderDiv7
{
    left:467px;
}
#sliderDiv8
{
    left:545px;
}
#sliderContainer
{
    position:absolute;
    top:615px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left: -500px;
    height: 150px;
    width:580px;
    cursor:none;
    overflow:hidden;


}
.busTypeRing
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top:240px;
    border: 10px solid blue;
    border-radius: 115px;
    z-index: 0;
    opacity: .5;

}
.busType
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top:250px;
    z-index: 3;
    cursor: pointer;

}
.busTypeBack
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top:250px;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity:.4;
}
.busType1
{

    left:50%;
    margin-left: -500px;

}
.busType2
{

    left:50%;
    margin-left: -100px;

}
.busType3
{

    left:50%;
    margin-left: 300px;

}
#busType1Ring
{

    left:50%;
    margin-left: -510px;


}
#busType2Ring
{

    left:50%;
    margin-left: -110px;
    opacity: 0;

}
#busType3Ring
{

    left:50%;
    margin-left: 290px;
    opacity: 0;
}
#slider
{
    position:absolute;
    height:100px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left: -564px;
    top:695px;
}

#sliderImage
{
    top:-20px;

    position:absolute;
    height:100px;
    left:40px;

}
#homeLinkBackground
{
    position:absolute;
   width: 80px;
    height: 27px;
   left:50%;
   top:115px;
   margin-left: -40px;
   z-index: 1;
    background-color: blue;
    opacity: .5;
    z-index: 0;
}
#homeLink
{
    position:absolute;
    width: 150px;
    left:50%;
    top:95px;
    margin-left: -75px;
    z-index: 2;
}
#pageDivider
{
    position:absolute;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: gray;
    top:139px;
    width:98%;
    left:1%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put everything inside a containing div with a size large enough to surround the page content, set the margins to auto on said div and overflow-x to hidden. It looks good now. I still haven't figured out why the window was made larger but this will work for those having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Make

```
 body
 {
  margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

use reset by Eric Meyer

```
html, body, div, span, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
abbr, address, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp,
small, strong, sub, sup, var,
b, i,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, figure, footer, header,&nbsp;hgroup, menu, nav, section, menu,
time, mark, audio, video {
margin:0;
padding:0;
border:0;
outline:0;
font-size:100%;
vertical-align:baseline;
background:transparent;
}

article, aside, figure, footer, header,
hgroup, nav, section { display:block; }

nav ul { list-style:none; }

blockquote, q { quotes:none; }

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after { content:''; content:none; }

a { margin:0; padding:0; font-size:100%; vertical-align:baseline; background:transparent; }

ins { background-color:#ff9; color:#000; text-decoration:none; }

mark { background-color:#ff9; color:#000; font-style:italic; font-weight:bold; }

del { text-decoration: line-through; }

abbr[title], dfn[title] { border-bottom:1px dotted #000; cursor:help; }

/* tables still need cellspacing="0" in the markup */
table { border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0; }

hr { display:block; height:1px; border:0; border-top:1px solid #ccc; margin:1em 0; padding:0; }

input, select { vertical-align:middle; }
/* END RESET CSS */
```

Or if it is still happen make a fiddle so we can judge the problem